# Can I create a Pod project using Swift and Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I want to create a pod project, I know that the easy way is choose or Swift or Objective-C. I have my library written in Objective-C, and I want to add some Swift files.

My question is: **If I have a mix project, with Swift and Objective C classes**, Can I create a Cocoapod project? or Cocoapod project should have only one language.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally mix languages in a Cocoapods project, what I would do is create the project as a Swift project, then `pod init` and install pods, and then create the bridging header and add the Objective-C files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can working with both languages in single project, if you want to use Objective C class in Swift files than you have to create one Header file, Here i sending you URL, just follow the steps.

http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c/how-to-use-objective-c-classes-in-swift/